# How to fix a "hidden" layout in list item on small screens (QVGA/HVGA)

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a row for `ListView` defined like this (screenshot from graphical view in Eclipse Android SDK):

[image: Eclipse IDE row]

The problem is that in this row **only on small screens** the last layout element (the star) is "hidden". On larger screens, the same layout XML looks/works as expected (and as seen in IDE).

This unexpected layout behavior happens on both **devices and emulators** and on **all versions** (API 8 - 19).

I have noticed the error on the (original) `LinearLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="72dp"
  android:background="@color/transparent" >

  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_row_checkBox_container"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <CheckBox
      android:id="@+id/list_row_checkBox"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:text="" />
  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_row_text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/list_row_txtTitle"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:text="Title"
      android:textSize="30sp" />

    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal" >

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_row_txtExtra1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:text="First" />

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_row_txtExtra2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:text="Second" />
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <!-- android:background="@color/green" -->

    <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/list_row_select_icon"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:background="@android:color/transparent"
      android:clickable="true"
      android:src="@drawable/btn_star_holo_light_off" />
  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Result:

[image: Cropped LinearLayout on HVGA emulator]

The star-button can be seen (in place) when I press on it:

[image: Cropped LinearLayout on HVGA emulator, star pressed]

After that, naturally, I have checked the Adapter (standard `ArrayAdapter` with view holder pattern) but there's nothing there apart from a `OnTouchListener` on the button. Next, I have tried changing the root layout of the row item, first to `RelativeLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="72dp"
  android:background="@color/transparent" >

  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_row_checkBox_container"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <CheckBox
      android:id="@+id/list_row_checkBox"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:text="" />
  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_row_text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="48dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_row_checkBox_container"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/list_row_txtTitle"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:text="Title"
      android:textSize="30sp" />

    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal" >

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_row_txtExtra1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:text="First" />

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_row_txtExtra2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:text="Second" />
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/list_row_select_icon"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:background="@android:color/transparent"
      android:clickable="true"
      android:src="@drawable/btn_star_holo_light_off" />
  </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Result:

[image: Cropped RelativeLayout on HVGA emulator]

And, lastly, I have tried the `FrameLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="72dp"
  android:background="@color/transparent" >

  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_row_checkBox_container"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top|left"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <CheckBox
      android:id="@+id/list_row_checkBox"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:text="" />
  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_row_text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top|left"
    android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="48dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/list_row_txtTitle"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:text="Title"
      android:textSize="30sp" />

    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal" >

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_row_txtExtra1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:text="First" />

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_row_txtExtra2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:text="Second" />
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top|right"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/list_row_select_icon"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:background="@android:color/transparent"
      android:clickable="true"
      android:src="@drawable/btn_star_holo_light_off" />
  </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Result:

[image: Cropped FrameLayout on HVGA emulator]

As can be seen, nothing helped and I'm a bit "puzzled".

**Ideas how to fix this, please?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add `drawable-mdpi` resources to the project for the `btn_star_holo_light_off` image (there were only `drawable-xhdpi` ones).

Answer (score 0):

First check that what device have you selected when you create a layout It should be on the top bar of your graphical layout xml. The default layout folder works with devices with 4 - 7 inch screen. However layout malfunction occurs on the basis of device DPI also. So you have to create multiple layout folders to support different layouts and their landscape folders as well.

You do not have to create so many layouts. It is because you have to create different layouts for different devices with different screen size and dpi. That is why the star is getting out of screen.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Go to this link and read it.